# Trouble assigning a tr1::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, shared-ptr

I've got a class that has a tr1::shared_ptr as a member, like so:

```
class Foo
{
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<TCODBsp> bsp;

    void Bar();
}
```

In member function Bar, I try to assign it like this:

`bsp = newTCODBsp(x,y,w,h);`

g++ then gives me this error

`no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((yarl::mapGen::MapGenerator*)this)->yarl::mapGen::MapGenerator::bsp = (operator new(40u), (<statement>, ((TCODBsp*)<anonymous>)))’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/tr1/shared_ptr.h:834: note: candidates are: std::tr1::shared_ptr<TCODBsp>& std::tr1::shared_ptr<TCODBsp>::operator=(const std::tr1::shared_ptr<TCODBsp>&)`

in my code, `Foo` is actually `yarl::mapGen::MapGenerator`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call `.reset(new TCODBsp)` or say `bsp = std::tr1::shared_ptr(new TCODBsp)`.  Shared pointers are explicit.  You can't just assign the ptr type to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a native pointer to a shared pointer.  The shared_ptr must be initialized with that value, or you can call reset() with the native pointer value.